# PHP - array_push is replacing instead of add to SESSION Variable

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

```
<?php 
session_start();
$pid = $_GET['pid']; 
$ptype = $_GET['ptype'];
$_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();

if (isset($_GET['add_cart']) && !empty($_GET['add_cart'])) {
  // Add new data to Session var

  $newdata = array($pid , $ptype, 1 );

  array_push($_SESSION['cart_items'], $newdata);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

`array_push` replaces the data already in the `$_SESSION` with `$newdata` variable in the `$_SESSION` instead of adding it.

For example:

I enter the url: `?pid=1&ptype=CH-&add_cart=Add+to+Cart`
And the array looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["cart_items"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "CH-"
      [2]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

That's great. But when I enter another url like: `?pid=1&ptype=CPU-&add_cart=Add+to+Cart`
The array looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  ["cart_items"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "CPU-"
      [2]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

instead of this:

```
array(1) {
  ["cart_items"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "CH-"
      [2]=>
      int(1)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "CPU-"
      [2]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
}
```

It replaces the data that was already in the Session. I want it to add to it. How do I do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you need this: `$_SESSION = array();` . Session is already an array even without you defining it explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

change lines 5&6 from

```
$_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
```

to

```
// $_SESSION = array();
// $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();
```

array_push wasn't clearing your data.   those two lines were clearing your session data on every page load.

Comment: Worked! Thanks! But could you explain why it didn't work with $_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array();

Comment: because everytime those two lines ran, you completely REPLACED the session with empty arrays. "Hey, why is this empty box here? I just put the box here and now my stuff is gone"

Comment: Oh ok. Makes sense. Thanks again